System hanging after fresh install of 24.04, especially using Files and Settings
Well, I haven't been able to restore my files yet, so I haven't tried much else...
I thought it was a windows rendering issue and I was patiently waiting for an update (I'm a farmer so I don't need or use the computer every day). First problems:

System was hanging when I was using Settings (to add new users, to not display unmounted volumes in the dock, ...)
When I right click on something in Files the pop-up flashes and doesn't display properly. As I move the cursor I can see the menu item I'm hovering over. Sometimes I can do what I want, other times the system hangs.

When the system hangs, the only thing I know how to do is a hard reboot by holding the power button down.
I was/am having problems restoring all my files, and in the process of checking if I can open files from an external HDD I discovered that I can't launch vlc. LibreOffice, Inkscape, GIMP are fine, but vlc won't launch (installed like the others as a snap through the App Center). I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling vlc but nothing changes.
Really I have no idea how to go about diagnosing or fixing these problems. I can't even think what to search for for help. Do I need to reinstall the whole system again?
Hardware: MSi H87M-E33 mobo, Intel Core i3-4130 3.40GHz, 8GB RAM, new Verbatim Vi550 S3 128GB SSD. Apart from the new SSD I've been running Ubuntu on this system since 2013.
Thanks in advance for any help.

See if you can open a terminal and reinstall the Gnome desktop.
Commands:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Or if the issue persists it could be a Gnome issue and you could try installing xfce4 instead.
Sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies


Thanks @NickP. I'll give that a try

In progress, although I see that's going to install Thunderbird and various other things that was happnot to have in the new minimal desktop...

Unfortunately the situation now seems worse. I reinstalled the Gnome desktop as per your guidance, rebooted, opened Files, right-clicked on the Documents folder and immediately the system hung forcing me to do a hard reboot. Worth a try though ;)

Have you tried other desktops?

Seems like it is a snap problem as Ubuntu is aggressively pushing in snaps.

Thanks @nick After over a week of trying to find solutions and get help from within the Ubuntu community, I finally gave up and installed MXLinux. Managed to restore my backups straight away, solved my long-standing problem with duplex printing, and maybe because of Xfce, the whole system is faster.
